# Spring Annotations - Injecting Map of Objects

Tags: java, spring

Using XML annotation , I am injecting a map using the below config -

```
   <bean id = "customerfactory" class = "com.brightstar.CustomerFactory">
        <property name = "getCustomerMap">
            <map key-type = "java.lang.String" value-type = "com.brightstar.CustomerImpl">
                <entry key = "DEFAULT" value-ref = "getDefaultImpl"></entry>
                <entry key = "PERSON" value-ref = "getPersonImpl"></entry>
                <entry key = "COMPANY" value-ref = "getCompanyImpl"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have created 3 beans - DefaultImpl , PersonImpl and CompanyImpl. How can I inject these as a map using Spring Annotation?

EDIT: For now , I have performed the below but not sure if it is the recommended approach

```
private Map<String, CustomerImpl> getCustomerMap ;
@Autowired
private GetDefaultImpl getDefaultImpl;
@Autowired
private GetPersonImpl getPersonImpl;
@Autowired
private GetCompanyImpl getCompanyImpl;

private static final String DEFAULT = "DEFAULT";
private static final String COM = "PERSON";
private static final String SOM = "COMPANY";


@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    getCustomerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,CustomerImpl>();
    getCustomerMap.put(DEFAULT, getDefaultImpl);
    getCustomerMap.put(PERSON, getPersonImpl);
    getCustomerMap.put(COMPANY, getCompanyImpl);        
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Inject a **Map which contains Objects**, (**Using Java Config**)

You can do like this...

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Autowired private WhiteColourHandler whiteColourHandler;

    @Bean public Map<ColourEnum, ColourHandler> colourHandlers() {
        Map<ColourEnum, ColourHandler> map = new EnumMap<>();
        map.put(WHITE, whiteColourHandler);
        //put more objects into this map here
        return map;
    }
}
```

====================

2.Inject a **Map which contains Strings** (**Using properties file**)

You can inject String values into a Map from the **properties file** using the **@Value** annotation and **SpEL** like this.

For example, below property in the properties file.

```
propertyname={key1:'value1',key2:'value2',....}
```

In your code,

```
@Value("#{${propertyname}}")  
private Map<String,String> propertyname;
```

**Note:** 1.The hashtag as part of the annotation.

```
    2.Values must be quotes, else you will get SpelEvaluationException
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case , I have to inject Objects which cannot be present in property file.

Comment: Thank you , this helps. Can you please comment on my approach as well? I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I am not sure, @Postconstruct is best practice to initialize bean or manage lifecycle of bean,because it is JEE standard, but not for injecting dependencies.But, Yes, best practices are not rules.

Comment: Thanks @Sundararaj!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my 2 cents. As far as I understood, you are implementing  factory pattern , switching between the implementations at runtime. So, it is code, not a configuration, ideal place for that to be in is code itself, not the properties file. I would go with the first approach that Sundararaj Govindasamy suggested.  I don't see any problem in @postConstruct method as well. But I would go with the former as its cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs !