# Spring. How to inject a dependence according on application arguments?

Tags: java, spring

I am new in Spring framework. I develop a standalone console application. App will get several files of different format ( CSV, JSP, XML) as arguments. I want inject a certain implementation of parser according to file format.

[my service and parsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAjJU.png)

These is my service:

```
@Service
public class ParsingService {

private final Parser parser;

@Autowired
public ParsingService(Parser parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
}

public List<Order> parse(String filePath) {
    try {
        return parser.parse(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

My main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConf.class);
    for (String arg : args) {
        ParsingService service = context.getBean(ParsingService.class);
        List<Order> listOfParsedObjects = service.parse(arg);
        listOfParsedObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
}
```

I will pass to command line several file paths and i need Spring to inject necessary implementation depending on file format.

Comment: Is `Parser` your own class/interface?

Comment: @ETO yes it is my interface

Comment: You can find my solution in a separate post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Parser` is your own interface you can add a method telling the format it's able to parse:

```
public interface Parser {
   List<Order> parse(String filePath);
   String getFormat();
}
```

Then override it in all the implementations:

```
@Component
public class CsvParser implements Parser {

    public static final String FORMAT = "csv";

    public String getFormat(){
        return FORMAT;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Configure your parser beans either by annotating the classes with @Bean/@Component or by creating instances in your config class. (If you're using SpringBoot I would suggest using `@ConditionalOn...` annotations in order to avoid creation of unnecessary beans)

Now you can inject all of your `Parser` instances into `ParserService`.

```
@Service
public class ParsingService {

    private final Map<String, Parser> parsers;

    @Autowired
    public ParsingService(List<Parser> allParsers) {
        this.parsers = allParsers
                           .stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Parser::getFormat, p -> p));
    }

    public List<Order> parse(String filePath) {
        try {
            String format = getFormat(filePath);
            Parser parser = parsers.get(format);
            if(parser == null) {
                // Replace this exception by a more appropriate one
                throw new RuntimeException("No parsers found for format : " + format);
            } else {
                return parser.parse(filePath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getFormat(String filePath){
        int i = filePath.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i > 0) {
            return filePath.substring(i+1).toLowerCase();
        } else {
            // Replace this exception by a more appropriate one
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot determine the file format!");
        }   
    }
}
```

This way neither your `ParserService` nor `Main` classes will depend from your custom `Parser` implementations. Once you need a new parser you can simply define a new class implementing the interface. No more changes needed.

**UPDATE**

Adding `Main` and `AppConfig` classes

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConf.class);
        ParsingService service = context.getBean(ParsingService.class);

        for (String arg : args) {
            List<Order> listOfParsedObjects = service.parse(arg);
            listOfParsedObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.root.package")
public class AppConf {
    // Do something here
}
```

For parallel processing try replacing your for-loop in `Main` with the following code:

```
 Arrays.stream(args)
       .parallel()
       .map(service::parse)
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or you can use an `ExecutorService`:

```
int poolSize = 3;
ExecutorService executorService =  new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

for (String arg : args) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        service.parse(arg).forEach(System.out::println);
    });
}
```

Comment: Added `Main` and `AppConfig`

Comment: Thank you, this solution  works fine. But i have another question. How to do this app in concurrency. So, i want to pass the array of files paths and app should parsing it in few threads.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to inject a collection of Parsers

```
@Autowired
private List<Parser> parsers;
```

And then choose the correct parser from that list.
Also, that is possible to do through a Map
[Spring Annotations - Injecting Map of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906383/spring-annotations-injecting-map-of-objects)

You can define the method in the parser interface, that returns a collection of extensions, like this

```
 public interface Parser {
    List<String> getExtensions();
}
```

Then you can utilize Java 8 streams for looking for correct parser:

```
parsers.stream().filter(p->p.getExtensions().contains(extension)).findFirst();
```

This will return the optional which may contain the needed parser
When you add a parser, what you need is to add a parser and define the extensions. No need to change the code in main

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case i can just get necessary parser from context scope without service? I just can check file format and execute context.getBean(parserIml.class).parse().
But I need more convenient solution, that i can just create new Implementation and inject it without changing of main method.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to consider using Spring Boot and the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation.  In the code example below, there will only ever be a bean called `csvParserImpl` if the property of `my.parser` has the value of `csv`.  By changing the property value from `csv` to `json`, `jsonParserImpl` will be created instead of `csvParserImpl`.  If `my.parser` is not defined or set to a value which doesn't include neither `csv` nor `json`, then there will be no instance of `Parser`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyAutoconfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name="my.parser", havingValue="csv")
  CsvParserImpl csvParserImpl() {
    return new CsvParserImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(name="my.parser", havingValue="json")
  JsonParserImpl jsonParserImpl() {
    return new JsonParserImpl();
  }
}
```

When I'm referring to "property", that has a specific meaning within spring boot.  [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) in spring boot can pull in property values from a multiple of sources, including environment variables, system variables, and command line variables.

Comment: i use a Spring Freamework, not Spring Boot. But i will try your solution. But first i need to undersand how to use Spring Boot =)  You solution looks interesting, i will try certainly.