# How to inject a Map in Spring @Value field?

Tags: java, spring

How can I inject the following `application.properties` into a `Map` field?

```
my.server.url=localhost
my.server.port=8080
my.server.timeout=10000
```

What is wrong with the following class?

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
public class MyService {
     private Map<String, String> server;
     public void setServer(Map<String, String> server) { this.server = server; }

    public MyService(WebClient.Builder builder) {
          this.builder = builder.uri(server.get("url")).build();
    }
}
```

Result:

> Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [MyService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39906684/5201238

Comment: No, still getting the same exception.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. Looking at Spring code, e.g `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties` use builder methods to transform the injected list an single string fields into `Map`s.

Comment: By bad, the problem is that inside the constructor the properties have not yet being injected, thus NPE.

Comment: @membersound, your property injection to `Map` should work. The exception you're posting is not related to your code, because you're getting `NPE` in constructor and in your code `NPE` is imossible in this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

create a bean as following in the configuration class :

```
@Bean(name = "appProperties")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
return bean;
```

}

And then inject the values in it as map as follows in to the desired class :

```
@Resource(name = "appProperties")
private Map<String, String> properties;
```